# How to approximate the integral of the standard normal distribution.

Tags: integration, power-series, normal-distribution

So I have this eqn.

$$
f(x)= \frac {e^ \frac{-x^2}{2}} {\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$

I need to find:

$$
\int\limits_{-1}^1 f(x)dx
$$

So I want to use this series to integrate. I know that:

$$
e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}
$$

So without considering the coefficient of the function, I can build my eqn into this series as such:

$$
e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2^nn!}
$$

This is where I get lost. What do I do with the coefficient of e. How do I build this into a series and include the coefficient of e:

$$
\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\
$$

Comment: you know that total probability is one and standard normal distribution ranges from -1 to 1 so your integral final value is 1

Comment: you cannot use elementary methods to integrate normal distribution and even if we use special function that will give the answer as an infinite series

Comment: ^ what!? the domain of standard normal distribution is not [-1,1].

Comment: Use linearity of summation.

Comment: lol domain for standard normal distribution is 

$$
(-\infty, \infty)
$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

$$
f(x)= \frac {e^ \frac{-x^2}{2}} {\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$

I need to find:

$$
\int\limits_{-1}^1 f(x)dx
$$

So I want to use this series to integrate. I know that:

$$
e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}
$$

So without considering the coefficient of the function, I can build my eqn into this series as such:

$$
 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}
$$

So we can just build up and get the origial.

$$
\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2^nn!}
$$

Then all we need to do is expand out the series to a few values of n, then we can anti-differentiate the series, and then we can solve using the FTC, where the integral from [a,b] = F(b) - F(a).

Comment: Almost! Note that when you replace $x$ with $-x^2/2$ in the Taylor series, you should get 
$$
 e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2^nn!}
$$
which for odd $n$ will be negative, but for even $n$ will be positive. 

So
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \sim 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^6), 
$$
which should converge when $x \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Yeah my algebra was off in the OP, but I ended up fixing it in my answer there. I ended up with exactly that series. And it did converge. And it ends up as 68%, which was kinda funny. And I ended up using the -1^n in my notes. It's a much clearer notation I agree.

Comment: Why is 68% funny? How many terms is this?

I think the 'true' value is roughly 0.68, which is good, this is the area under the bell curve from -1 std deviation to +1 std deviation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean funny as in incorrect. I like math, so I get a kick out of things like this.

Comment: Yep, consistency is the beautiful thing about maths :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You cannot find an explicit answer for your integration. However the integration of normal distribution can be stated  in terms of [Q Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function). 
$$
Q(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}dt
$$
There are various estimates for this function which may be useful. For instance for $x>0$:
$$
\frac{x}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \leq Q(t)\leq \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}
$$

**Remark:** If you want to continue working with series, it is enough to take the coefficient of the exponential function out of the integration.

Comment: Thanks for the input. There is actually a very easy way to approximate this integral. Note that, since I'm working on an approximation, we don't need to use an infinite series. Rather, we can consider that n goes to 5 or some arbitrary number, and get an approximation of the integral of f(x).

And as you said, you can actually take the coefficient right out. 

I will answer below.